# Pass package name into Gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Is it possbile to pass things such as the Package.json name into a Gulp task? For instance, something like:

```
<%= pkg.name %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `require` the `package.json` and it'll return as an object.

```
var pkg = require('./package.json');

gulp.task('default', function() {
   console.log(pkg.name);
}
```

Comment: oh! Could this be pass into the template html at all, so that I could in theory set the html title to that of the package name?

Comment: With a bit of work yes, but my best guess is that you need something like [gulp-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-template/)